# Angular 2 Cast FormGroup value to interface

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am trying to cast the content of my FormGroup value into an interface which I want use for posting something to my Web Api.

My interface looks like this:

```
export interface MoneyItemI {
  Description: string;
  Amount: number;
}
```

My submit methods looks like this:

```
onSubmit() {
    let jsonString = JSON.stringify(this.itemForm.value);
    let mi = <MoneyItemI>JSON.parse(jsonString);
}
```

I can see that I get an object created with JSON.parse but unfortunately it does not look like it an valid MoneyItemI object for me.

Property 'Amount' for example is not a number. It is assigned like a string.

How can I create a valid interface with the value of my FormGroup?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Does `this.itemForm.value` have the correct `Amount` and `Description` properties before you call `JSON.stringify(this.itemForm.value)`?

If so, you should be able to just do:

`let mi = <MoneyItemI>this.itemForm.value;`

Comment: There was a typo in my code. Your post pointed me in the right direction, therefore I mark your post as an accepted answer.